# Python/Maya simple script for scaling keyframes

Tags: python, animation, maya, keyframe

I am writing a script with Python on Maya to allow me to scale selected keyframes by a certain number.

Basically, if I animate on ones I can easily scale all the keyframes to be 2 keyframes apart.  Since I am a beginner the script should be extremely primitive, as I still do some manual work (Selecting the object and keyframes).

I just need a script that will scale them for me automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started with maya python scripting, select all the keyframes then:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
mc.scaleKey(timeScale=2, timePivot=0)
```